# Utilizando o setInterval

Tags: javascript

Como posso atualizar uma div usando o setInterval?

Comment: Sim, mas quando uso o javascript o meu browser fica travando. Não tem como fazer essa atualização do lado do servidor?

Comment: Talvez tenha sido mal feito mesmo o meu script. no meu body, tenho uma div chamada corpo e quero atualizar ela de 10 em 10 segundos. Você sabe que javascript eu deveria fazer para essa atualização?

Comment: Francis, acho que você entendeu errado. Coloque o código que você fez e deu problema. A pergunta da maneira que está é ampla demais e não te ajudará em nada. Por este motivo, irei para votar para fechá-la. Aproveite e leia o guia de [ask].

Comment: 10 em 10 segundos: `setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById("id_da_div").innerHTML = 'nova_informacao'; },10000);`. O tempo é calculado em milissegundos, portanto 10000 = 10 segundos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode atualizar a div com o `innerHTML` dentro do `setInterval`.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("relogio").innerHTML = new Date();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="relogio"></div>
```

Sintaxe básica do `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(<function>, <milliseconds>);
```

Mais sobre `setInterval`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp